# Java String Concatenation Error "String index out of range: -1"

Tags: java, string

First off I know there are a lot of questions about "String index out of range", I have looked through them but can't find anyone having the same problem as me.

I have to write a simple program:

Given a string, return a "rotated left n" version where the first n chars are moved to the end.

```
leftN("Hello",2) → "lloHe"
leftN("java",0) → "java"
leftN("Hi,1") → "iH"
```

So I wrote the following:

```
package string;

public class LeftN {
    public static String leftN(String str, int n) {
        if (str.length() > 1 && n > 0) {
            String a = str.substring(n);
            String b = str.substring(0, n);
            return a + b;
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**
When I return just `a` or just `b` I get a valid output (if I add the output of `a` and `b` on paper I am getting the `rotated left n` version of the string). However, when I return the concatenation of `a + b` I get the `String index out of range: -1` error, what can it be that is causing this?

Now I know that this error has to do with referencing a value that is out of bounds for the string and understand how this works when creating a substring. What is really confusing me is how adding two seemingly valid strings can give me this error?

**Note:** I have a test class provided that I am testing it against to see if it's giving the right output but I am not sure if I am allowed to post it online so that is why I am not providing it.

Comment: Note that a more efficient way to do this is with a `StringBuilder`: `return new StringBuilder(str.length()).append(str, n, str.length()).append(str, 0, n).toString();`.

Comment: `if (str.length() > 1 && n > 0 && str.length() >= n) ` this is fine.. unless you don't want a nested iteration over and over if the length is greater than number.

Comment: I just wonder about "When I return just a or just b I get a valid output" - are you sure? Also would have been helpful if the data causing the error was given in question

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes I am sure. E.g. when I would have the input ```Hello``` and ```n = 2``` then I would get ```llo``` for ```a``` and ```He``` for ```b```. However, when adding the two strings it would throw the exception.

Comment: well, I doubt you get the exception for the same input values when returning `a + b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your exception by passing an `n` greater than the length of `str`:

```
leftN("abc", 4);
```

[results in](https://ideone.com/NxfP4f):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1850)
    at Ideone.leftN(Main.java:12)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:22)
```

You need to handle the case of `n` being too large (or, indeed, negative). For example:

- Throw an `IllegalArgumentException`
- Use `n % str.length()` instead.

Comment: I added the condition ```str.length() >= n``` to the if statement and it works now.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily describe that as "working". It wouldn't throw the exception, but that doesn't mean that it does what one might expect. I would expect that rotating left by n them rotating left by m would be the same as rotating left by (n+m). (Of course, there's also the -ve shift case to handle, too).

Comment: Is it better to throw an exception if n is larger than the string length?

Comment: @Isak yes. Throwing an exception is an indication that something unexpected has happened. Like in your case, the shifting number is greater than the string length SHOULD be considered as **Unexpected** behaviour. Returning just the same string is hiding the unexpected behaviour. 

Can you distinguish between the cases `leftN("Hello", 5)` and `leftN("Hello", 9)` ?? No.. right. Coz both produces same output. `Hello`. Throwing exception is advisable :)

Comment: @miiiii not necessarily. As I have stated, it is not unreasonable to expect `leftN` invocations to compose. What you choose to do depends upon your requirements. What is definitely wrong is silently not handling the case (as in your "Can you distinguish" example).

Comment: @AndyTurner exactly. It's not necessity, it highly depends on what is in the requirements..!! my example is based on the solution on which post owner agreed (putting one more condition in `if` ) and return same string if it not matches the rule.

Comment: you can reproduce the issue? also the "When I return just a or just b I get a valid output" part? [:-) Exception or not, both are valid ("first n chars" does not allow `n` larger then length), but should be documented!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I can reproduce the exception with the given code for an input of my choosing, via the linked Ideone snippet.

Comment: you get a valid output if only returning `a` or `b`, without sum >>> "When I return just a or just b I get a valid output" ?? (please read the full comment, not just first sentece... and also consider the smiley, despite not that obvious[wearing a hut])